# NoClassDefFound Exception when trying to use custom external widget

Tags: android, android-fragments, calendar, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to implement Caldroid (https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) in my own project. I looked at the sample app given and it had the app separate from the project that defined the widget. I have done the same thing. The code compiles, but when I try to run the app I am getting a NoClassDefFound exception when trying to call the widget. Here is the code for setting up the calendar

```
private void calendarSetup(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        caldroidFragment.restoreStatesFromKey(savedInstanceState,
                "CALDROID_SAVED_STATE");
    }
    // If activity is created from fresh
    else {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        args.putBoolean(CaldroidFragment.ENABLE_SWIPE, true);
        args.putBoolean(CaldroidFragment.SIX_WEEKS_IN_CALENDAR, true);

        caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);
    }

    // Attach to the activity
    FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.calendar, caldroidFragment);
    t.commit();

}
```

Here is the logcat

```
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563): Process: com.example.app, PID: 2563
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.example.app.fragments.MyActivity.calendarSetup(app.java:123)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.example.app.fragments.MyActivity.onCreateView(app.java:68)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-13 17:24:30.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The line at which the error is occurring is when I try to instantiate a CaldroidFragment.

I have added the external project to the build path of this current one as has been mentioned in other SO answers. However this doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Eclipse with most updated ADT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have added the external project to the build path of this current one as has been mentioned in other SO answers.

None of those answers are right. If you are manually manipulating the build path in Eclipse, you're probably doing it wrong.

For a third-party library that is a JAR, copy it into `libs/`, and you are done. Do not alter the build path manually.

For a third-party library that is an Android library project — as Caldroid is — you need to import the library into your Eclipse workspace, then attach the library to your app project via Project > Properties > Android. This is covered in greater detail in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject). Do not alter the build path manually.